# Looking for title/author of sci-fi book from the 80s/90s, environmentalist theme, older female protagonist

Tags: story-identification, virus

I read this book in my teens (90s) so it's no newer than say 1995. The plot revolved around an older woman on the west coast of America (possibly San Franciso or San Deigo) during a time when climate change/global warming has made life difficult for humanity. Climate change progressed at an "exponential rate" (I remember that specific phrase from the book) and due to a lack of resources, many people live together in quasi-communes and grow as much as they can in gardens.

Here's the most distinctive thing I remember: It is discovered that humans have the genetic potential to care about the environment (by increasing their sensitivity to it or something like that), and the protagonist somehow became aware of or involved in a conspiracy or plot to create and release a virus that will switch this gene on in every human. The result will be a population that will better steward the planet and not greedily consume it. The term "The Green Man" was relevant in some way; I think as the inspiration for the eco-terrorists to create the virus, or maybe as a code for recognizing those in on the project.
I also believe this book was penned by a female author, although I may be mistaken.

Answer (score 6):

This is most likely the book [Overshoot](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0441005098) by Mona Clee.

From the Amazon summary:

> Eighty-year old Moira Burke had expected life to end with nuclear war--simply and quickly. But by 2032, global warming had become the real threat. And a bold new experiment called "The Green Man" had become the only hope.

Answer (score 5):

The timeframe is a bit off, but this sounds very similar to Margaret Atwood's paired books "The Year of the Flood" and "Oryx and Crake".  I never finished reading either book, but I do remember that an older female protagonist, global warming and cult of gardeners all figure prominently in "Year of the Flood."   According to Wikipedia it is a prequel of sorts to Atwood's earlier "Oryx and Crake," which revolves around a genetically engineered virus with ecological implications.